# Is it better practice to store system variables in SQL or $_SESSION in php web development?

Tags: php, sql, session, variables, system

I have a php/SQL web development question.  Is it better to use an SQL `SELECT` every page view to get system variables or better to store system variables in a `$_SESSION` variables?

`$_SESSION` variables would be quicker I imagine, but because I need to worry about synchronization if a system variable changes, I have to check the SQL database for a "last_synchronized" variable anyway that has the time the system variables were last updated and compare this to a `$_SESSION` variable for when the system variables were last updated for that session every page view.  Am I over-complicating it?  Would it be better practice to just refresh the system variables with an SQL select every page view?

Comment: if synchronization is `priority`, query DB everytime

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION for data you need almost all the time
Database for less important things.

Think about performance hit you would take querying your database after each click.
But it all really depends on how many SQL queries you expect to be getting. If you're building a website for many many users, it would be better to use the session array.

If it's only you, you won't notice any difference in performance.